# Next val of squence returns always null

Tags: oracle, session

I'm trying to check the next val of a sequence.

Here is the method :

```
public Long getCodeCommercialOffer(final String seq) {
  final Session session = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
  Query q= (Query) session.createQuery("SELECT " + seq + ".nextval FROM dual");
  return (Long) q.getSingleResult();
}
```

Why the return is always null ?

Comment: It seems odd to be selecting from a sequence like that. Why not reference the sequence directly when you insert data into the system, and use RETURNING to get the value that was assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, finally I found out the solution.

The problem is the cast, i replace it with BigDecimal instead of Long

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what value you are passing in as the seq name.  You might need to append the schema name to the front of the sequence (ex: mySchema.sequenceName).  I recommend that you print out the SQL statement you are trying to run, run that statement alone in a database query tool (ex: TOAD), tune the SQL to get it working, then put it back into the code.